# Android Studio - Project structure icon (check sign)

Tags: android, android-studio

All of sudden, one of my android studio projects (structure) started showing a icon (like a check sign) on the right side of a folder.

[image: Print-Screen]

I've already search on Internet and documentation (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/symbols.html) but was unable to find it.

I do not know if this "additional" icon is related with the file structure (what exaclty?) or some property that I changed (which one?) or something related with version control? or if I will have unexpected side effects because of it?

Does anyone nows the meaning? and how to revert\remove it?

Comment: It's the sign for a bookmark. Check the question I linked to.

Comment: Thank you for solving this mystery. Sorry for the duplicate, but I have been using different search terms "Android Studio" and "sign" (instead of "IntelliJ" and "symbol") for a few weeks and never found an answer for my question. I also had no idea that we could place a bookmark on that specific place and not in a million years I would guess or suspect of a bookmark.